# How to Handle different sibling objects (not models) in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an Order Controller store function which handles Order creation for several type of orders (Sales Order, Purchase Order etc). These all orders are stored in the same orders table.

But each type of order has some different functionalities. according to their attributes. (printing invoices, sending notifications etc)

These are the questions that I have

1. Since there is one Order Model how to handle these types of scenarios in Laravel?
2. If I need to create separate objects according to their type where I have to put these classes in the Laravel project?
3. How to map request data with these objects in Laravel?

What I currently thought of doing is in the store function. (I was said to use one route for all of this)

```
$order = null;
switch ($request->json('order_type')) {
    case 'sales':
        $order = new SalesOrder;
        $order->total = $request->json('total');
        ...
        break;
    case 'purchase':
        $order = new PurchaseOrder;
        $order->total = $request->json('total');
        ...
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `Interface` and `Concrete Class` for each scenario and a `Factory` pattern for creating the object

1. For the interface you will make an `OrderInterface`

```
interface OrderInterface
{
    public function make(Request $request);
}
```

2. For the concrete classes you will do

```
class Purchase implements OrderInterface
{

    public function make(Request $request)
    {
       ...
    }
}

class Sales implements OrderInterface
{

    public function make(Request $request)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

3. For the factory

```
class OrderFactory
{
    public static function make(string $type)
    {
        if ($type === 'sales') {
            return new Sales();
        } elseif ($type === 'purchase') {
            return new Purchase();
        }
    }
}
```

In your controller you will do

```
$order = OrderFactory::make($request->json('order_type'));
$order->make($request);
```

Now you have a very clean and readable way of creating the order object, this gives you more abstraction and encapsulated way of creating the object.

**Another solution** - but it's a Laravel stuff

Same as above except the factory part we will use Laravel `serviceContainer` and `Binding` so you will do

1. In your controller you will accept an object of `OrderInterface` like so

```
public function makeOrder(OrderInterface $order) {
   $order->make($request);
}
```

2. In you `AppServiceProvider`

```
$this->app->singleton(OrderInterface::class, function ($app) {
    if (request()->get('order_type') === 'sales') {
        return new Sales();
    } elseif (request()->get('order_type') === 'purchase') {
        return new Purchase();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. How to save this created Sales or Purchase order in orders table using Order mode?

Comment: Well if i got your question right you will add the creation code in each corresponding class for example in `Sales` class you will add `public function make(Request $request)
    {
       $order = new SalesOrder;
        $order->total = $request->json('total');
        ...
    }`

Comment: oh.. now I got it

Comment: I modified your first solution. without using an interface I used an abstract class named "order". because there are some reusable functions in the order types. Kept the make function as abstract. Will it be fine?

Comment: Yes totally fine, and that's where to use abstract when your sub classes have a common shared methods so you will define those methods in the abstract `order`.